# Django form buttons

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I have an order form that should display product sizes as buttons, but the buttons do not register to be selected unless a user clicks exactly on the letter for the size ('S', 'M', etc.) in the exact center of the button. Clicking the space between the letter and the border of the button marks it as selected, but when you click Add to cart, it deselects itself.

```
class OrderForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.instance = instance
    
        self.fields['size'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=self.instance.sizes.all(),
            widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
{% for choice in order_form.size %}
    <button type="button" class="size-btn">{{ choice }}</button>
{% endfor %}
```

Sizes is a simple model:

```
class Size(models.Model):
    size = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.size
```

This way the rendered HTML is a mess:

```
<button type="button" class="size-btn">
    <label for="id_size_0">
        <input type="radio" name="size" value="2" id="id_size_0" required>S
    </label>
</button>
```

How do I fix the buttons so that they get selected even if clicked outside of the very center, in the size letter?
Thanks.

Comment: can you please share an image of the button how It looks

Comment: [Here are the buttons.](https://ibb.co/g9nbv1y)

Answer (score 0):

This is only for the one-button customization according to your choice.
I would recommend you to use for loop or while loop to activate or deactivate the input

```
 <button
            type="button"
            id="button1"
            class="size-btn"
            onclick="checktheButton()"
        >
            <label for="id_size_0">
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="size"
                    value="2"
                    id="id_size_0"
                    required
                />S
            </label>
        </button>
        <script>
            const checktheButton = () => {
                document.querySelector("#id_size_0").check = true;
            };
        </script>
```

Comment: I'm already using a for loop to display all sizes with a foreign key to the specific product instance: {% for choice in order_form.size %} <button type="button" class="size-btn">{{ choice }}</button> {% endfor %}. *I think* he problem is me using widget=forms.RadioSelect() for the sizes field and the autogenerated HTML becomes a mess...